# Designing logic for grouping of variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Suppose we have a variable called `group` which contains grouping information

```
group = [ {1}, {2}, ..., {D} ]
```

We have to maintain a counter for every pair `(i, j)` where i, j are in the range [1 D] and for all those pairs whose `count(i, j) >= 5`, these pairs are merged.

**Example**:

```
D = 5
group = [ {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5} ]
(1, 2) = 7
(2, 3) = 10
(3, 4) = 2
(4, 5) = 20
```

hence pairs are merged and the resultant group is

```
group = [ {1 2 3}, {4 5} ]
```

in my problem `D` can have a value of `1000`, what is the efficient way to implement this logic

Comment: the pairs are only consecutive numbers or any numbers in `[1,D]` interval? For example, a pair can be `(2,5)`?

Comment: @user2999345 pairs need not be consecutive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `count>=5` as adjacency matrix and generate a `graph`:

```
% generating random count matrix
D = 20;
count = zeros(D);
count( randsample(D^2,round(D/2)) ) = 10;
% find connections
A = count  >= 5;
% A is symmetric - if (1,2) so (2,1) as well
A = A | A';
% build graph
G = graph(A);
% get connected components labeling from graph
idxs = G.conncomp;
% generate groups of nodes
nodes = num2cell(1:max(idxs));
group = cellfun(@(g) find(g == idxs),nodes,'UniformOutput',0);
% plot graph
plot(G)
```

[image]

Comment: In which library `graph` function is defined

Comment: I think [graph](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.html) is in the basic MATLAB, but was introduced in 2015b.

Comment: What a coincidence, I'm using 2015a :)

Comment: try using this [FEX entry](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42040-find-network-components)